# Enable USPS in Magento

Tags: magento, usps

I'm trying to enable USPS in Magento. I already created an account for USPS and ask their staff to move it to production server.

Then I fill up all necessary fields in System -> Configuration -> Shipping method -> USPS. I tried to search around and corrected all fields but I'm still unable to make it works.

I have enabled debug in USPS module and catch below response from USPS (there's no error at all):

```
<RateV4Response>
<Package ID="0">
<ZipOrigination>92672</ZipOrigination>
<ZipDestination>90503</ZipDestination>
<Pounds>0</Pounds>
<Ounces>0.2</Ounces>
<Size>REGULAR</Size>
<Machinable>TRUE</Machinable>
<Zone>1</Zone>
<Postage CLASSID="3">
<MailService>
Priority Mail Express 1-Day&lt;sup&gt;&#8482;&lt;/sup&gt;
</MailService>
<Rate>14.10</Rate>
</Postage>
<Postage CLASSID="2">
<MailService>
Priority Mail Express 1-Day&lt;sup&gt;&#8482;&lt;/sup&gt; Hold For Pickup
</MailService>
<Rate>14.10</Rate>
</Postage>
<Postage CLASSID="55">
<MailService>
Priority Mail Express 1-Day&lt;sup&gt;&#8482;&lt;/sup&gt; Flat Rate Boxes
</MailService>
<Rate>39.95</Rate>
</Postage>
</Package>
</RateV4Response>
```

It seems that I have received correct data, however in front-end, I still only see "This shipping method is currently unavailable...."

Do you have any idea about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Magento and have you applied the July 28 patches so Magento now recognizes Priority Mail Express as having replaced Express Mail?

[July 28 USPS API update patch](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/magento-community-edition-alert-important-patch-for-usps-api/)

There are two listed for each version except 1.7.x and they have to be applied in the proper order. The first one upgrades the **Shipping Methods subsystem** and the second one enables the **USPS API & Service Name change**.